# disable removing WordPress widgets but allow to change position/sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, widget

In a WordPress project I am adding widgets dynamically via the array $sidebars_widgets(); Most of the widgets are allowed to be removed by the user but some of them shouldn't be allowed to remove.

For example, there is one widget which may be repositioned or even moved to another sidebar but you can NOT remove it.

Hardcoding it into the html isn't an option since that makes it impossible to change the order.

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just check if this specific widget is present or not in sidebar_widgets. If it's not, then add it back.

Comment: WordPress don't have a separately capability for this task. You can check for include of the widget and if is not include, add back. However you can remove the drag/drop and delete option via jquery in the back end GUI.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll add it again or just hardcore it than.